# Use already selected cells in query

Tags: mysql, database

I want to know if I in MySQL have the possibility to make a math statement with a selection I have made earlier in the query? E.g.:

```
SELECT
 t.date as the_date,
 TIMETODIFF(the_date, NOW()) as date_diff,
 t.time_interval as t_interval,
 (date_diff / t_interval) as intervals_left
WHERE
 something = something
ORDER BY
 something DESC
```

My problem is, that i cant use the name, I give the selections. e.g when I use "the_date" to calculate the date_diff, it says "unknown column".

Comment: What is your problem exactely? It is unclear what you want to achive and what isn't working

Comment: Further described in the question. It is actually a quite simple question, but I can't see the logic in making it impossible to use the names I give the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias you defined in the `select`part in that part again. You could use it in the `where`part of your query or other later parts.

Comment: Thanks - that's just the answer I searched.. If it was possible it wasn't necessary to make some quite messy queries - but now i know, that it is. Thanks a lot :)